# Ionic 3 Image Upload using put method

Tags: ionic3, angular5, httpclient, put, image-upload

Need to Request: PUT to transfer an image from gallery or camera Android/IOS

Like:

```
return this.httpClient.put(endPointUrl, file, { headers: headers })
      .catch((error: any) => Observable.throw(error));
```

Using

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-file-transfer
npm install --save @ionic-native/transfer
```

it uses file transfer object to upload the image

```
const fileTransfer: TransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
     fileKey: 'file',
     fileName: 'name.jpg',
     headers: {}

  }

 fileTransfer.upload(imageDataLocalURL, 'http://localhost/ionic/upload.php',  options1)
.then((data) => {
 // success
 alert("success");
}, (err) => {
 // error
 alert("error"+JSON.stringify(err));
});
```

Is there any other way to combine it or figure out?

Comment: I guess you should want to use post rather than put here. But based on your question context it is still unclear what the problem is?

Comment: correct @SergeyRudenko but I have to use PUT as the backend is dynamoDB and AWS, and file transfer have its own method Upload with URL but there is no option mention for PUT method.

Comment: You can use `httpMethod: 'PUT'` in options1 for set put method